# Protractor seems to hang on specific tests when running them sequentially.

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I just wanted to post this here to see if i could get some traction on this issue.

I have a suite of tests im running using protractor and all of these tests run successfully. However, the catch here is that if i run them sequentially, one of them will hang (as if the page is not ready to move to next test case). And it will eventually die. The test case will freeze on the browser session and nothing can be done other than close the session.

The interesting part of this is that all of these test cases are functional and can be run independently but NOT sequentially (where this freeze happens). There are not enough logging information even using --verbose that will clarify the reason of the "in between" freezes.

Posting some of the protractor logging in case someone has seen or experienced something similar. This is after the 3 previous tests of the suite have passed:

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow. The last active task was: 
WebDriver.navigate().to(data:text/html,<html></html>)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:345:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.Navigation.to (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:1031:23)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:723:26)
    at [object Object].Protractor.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:1303:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:1388:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)'
```

At any rate, this might be a bit vague but i figured id ask someone here prior to moving to different testing solutions.

Thanks a lot!